# jQuery.getJSON - Passing Parameters with Different Data Type

Tags: c#, jquery, getjson

Scenario: Passing an object to Controller works but passing 2 parameters with different types (object, string) does not. 2 sample scenarios below:

**Working Scenario**

JS:

```
function someEventFunction() {
    var firstParam = {
        'Name' : 'Kevin',
        'Age' : 20
     };

    $.getJSON('Home/SomeURL', firstParam, function(response){
            //some code
    });
}
```

C#:

```
public JsonResult SomeURL(SomeModel pSomeModel)
{
    return Json("Success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Non-working Scenario**

JS:

```
function someEventFunction() {
    var firstParam = {
        'Name' : 'Kevin',
        'Age' : 20
     };

    var secondParam = 'some string';

    $.getJSON('Home/SomeURL', {
            pSomeModel: firstParam,
            pSomeString: secondParam
        }, function(response){
            //some code
    });
}
```

C#:

```
public JsonResult SomeURL(SomeModel pSomeModel, string pSomeString)
{
    return Json("Success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Seems like I'm doing something wrong when passing something else with an object. Can anybody tell me what's wrong?

Comment: The difference is in the example that works, jQuery is sending `Name=Kevin&Age=20` but after you add second parameter is sending `pSomeModel[Name]:Kevin&pSomeModel[Age]:20&pSomeString:some string`. I noticed pSomeModel looks like a dictionary. In fact it works if you get `public JsonResult SomeURL(Dictionary<string,string> pSomeModel, string pSomeString) { ...}` But I don't know if you can send a list of complex objects and get them parsed as separate objects at server. I typically send either one complex object or a list of simple types like int or string.